# Numbering set to wrong number when i tried to add page number

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

My numbering works fine and start at 1.1 and so on until i start to add page number.
My numbering becomes 5.1 and it seems to follow the page number because if i try to add numbering on previous pages it becomes 4.1 and so on.

How to make my numbering reset back to 1.1? Because my numbering does not start at first page.

Answer (score 0):

So I fix this by force but I don't know if this is the correct way or not.

- Right click the numbering I want to change
- Select adjust list indent
- Change the number format to 1.1
- Set apply changes to this point onward

Then update table of contents and it's showing perfectly.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Here is my writing on Page Numbers in Word. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers Are you doing page numbering or list numbering? See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's Numbering Front Matter: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm